# Modify code for extracting table information from a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the below code which gets information from table on a webpage. The code goes to the links of these webpages one by one, and gets the table data. This however works when the entries in table are all contained within the 'td' tag, here the entries that are supposed to be headers in the csv file are in 'th' tag. Could somebody help me with the modifications to the code in that case?

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
def cpap_spider(max_pages):
    global row_i
    page=1
    while page<=max_pages:
        url= "https://dmesupplyusa.com/bath-aids.html?p=" +str(page)
        source_code= requests.get(url)
        plain_text= source_code.text
        soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-item-link"}):
            href=link.get("href")
            title = link.string
            worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
            each_item(href)
            print(href)
            #print(title)
        page+=1

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"data table additional-attributes"})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('all_appended.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Title")
    
cpap_spider(4)
#each_item("https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical")       
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide a url that works as desired and one that doesn't and indicate what the desired result for the failing case should look like?

Comment: I realise the question was not clearly framed. I have updated it. Please check

Comment: Without looking at page you might get away with changing _cols = row.find_all('td')_ for _cols = row.select('th,td')_

Comment: You are most welcome